# Would I still be a valid volunteer examiner?

Tags: license, arrl

I'm currently an ARRL member, and a volunteer examiner under the ARRL/VEC.  I find myself needing to cut back on expenses this year and may end up dropping the ARRL membership.  If I do so, am I still a valid examiner under the ARRL/VEC?  If so, will I also be able to renew with ARRL/VEC when my renewal date comes up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the current [Volunteer Examiner manual from ARRL](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/VEs/VE%20Manual%20Web%20FINAL%202013.pdf), you can meet the requirements without becoming an ARRL member, and your VE status is only affected by your license status:

> As a Volunteer Examiner (VE), you are the gatekeeper to the integrity of the Volunteer Examiner Program. To that end, you must have certain qualifications and be accredited by a Volunteer Examiner Coordinator.
>
> To qualify to be a Volunteer Examiner, you must:
>
> - be 18 years of age or older; and
> - never have had your amateur station or operator licenses suspended or revoked; and
> - hold a valid General, Advanced or Extra Class license.[97.509]
>
> If you meet these criteria, the ARRL/VEC would like to hear from you. To be accredited by the ARRL/VEC, you must complete a training program. Examiners may be accredited by more than one VEC. VEs are not required to work with only one VE Team or VEC and are not restricted to any particular area. A VEC does not have to accept the services of a VE if it
> does not want to.

Further, even if there were such a requirement to become one, it doesn't expire on any other basis except that of your FCC license:

> Once accredited as an examiner in the ARRL/VEC’s program, your accreditation credentials will be good until your FCC license expires. Your accreditation is valid at any ARRL/VEC coordinated session.

I expect that as it is a voluntary position through the FCC granted by an act of congress, they can't make membership in their organization a requirement to be accredited by them.  [You can be accredited by another VEC](http://wireless.fcc.gov/services/index.htm?job=licensing_5&id=amateur), though, if the ARRL terms don't meet your needs.

Comment: This is correct. The process for becoming VEC accredited through the ARRL is completely separate from membership. I applied as a non-member, and don't recall feeling any pressure to subscribe in that process.